# Chapters and Formatting Headers

Tags: include, preamble

When I am composing a large document in LaTeX, I often compose the chapters in separate documents. When I do this I have to copy and paste a large block of header text to the chapter I am editing so I can make sure the formatting is correct while I am writing it.

How can I import a header file of formatting information with a single line?

Answer (score 11):

Solution 1: Put everything up to your \begin{document} in a separate file, say, preamble.tex. You can load this file in your document by saying \input{preamble}.

Solution 2: Almost the other way around: put your chapters in separate files, and have a main file like this

```
\documentclass...
.
.
.
\includeonly{chapter2}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
.
.
\end{document}
```

which will cause LaTeX to skip all the other chapters and only use chapter2.tex when you compile main.tex. (You can also list multiple chapters like so: \includeonly{chapter1,chapter7}.)

Comment: I have a problem: what should and what should not be present in chapters - those "\include"d files?
It is so obvious maybe that noone writes about it. And I have mistakes. Maybe because I repeated the same preamble in parent and every child files?

Comment: @Kotek [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 7):

Put it in a file called `header.tex` and in your main chapter put `\input{header.tex}`.

But, you might be better off creating a master file that has the header text in it, then `\include`s the chapters.

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{my awesome book}
\author{me}
\date{\today}

\includeonly{ch1}
\begin{document}
\include{ch1.tex}
\include{ch2.tex}
...
\end{document}
```

Changing the `\includeonly` line allows you to switch on and off what gets included.  So you could only include the chapter you were working on to make compiling quicker.

Comment: Also, calling them ch1 and not chapter1 will let you be 20 seconds faster in posting answers. :D

Comment: @Ulrich: lol.  I think `ch01-<subject-of-chapter-1>.tex`, etc., would be even better, but slower.

Answer (score 2):

You can also embed the command `\input` if you want something to appear irrespective of the `\include` commands:

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{my awesome book}
\author{me}
\date{\today}

\includeonly{ch1}
\begin{document}
\include{ch1.tex}
\include{ch2.tex}
...
\input{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user1999: good point.  I took the liberty of putting backticks around your inline code so it looks like code.

Comment: Good, I never understood the difference between the two...